# Redirecting with a 201 created

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Is there a way to redirect through a 201 answer?

The RFC specifies that the newly created resource must be specified in the `Location` header, and I do specify it. I assumed that the browser would redirect but it doesn't, even if the page has no content.

I want the user, after the POST action, to get redirected to the new resource. I'm therefore tempted to use `303 See Other` but a 201 seems more appropriate.

So, is there any way to automatically redirect popular browsers without user intervention and without relying on Javascript?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you're confusing two different semantic responses - one is telling the client that you successfully created a resource, and where it is. Whether the client goes to fetch it or not is a different story.

The second is telling the client that it has sent the wrong location URI for a resource it's requesting - and that it should try again, but with a different URI.

A 303 is appropriate in this case - in fact, it's explicitly recommended for this:

(from [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4))

It is primarily used to allow the output of a POST action to redirect the user agent to a selected resource, since doing so provides the information corresponding to the POST response in a form that can be separately identified, bookmarked, and cached, independent of the original request.

Comment: "The second is telling the client that it has sent the wrong location URI for a resource it's requesting" only if the request method was GET.  Sometimes it's legitimate to POST to a resource and have it create a new sub-resource with a different URI.

Answer (score 4):

The browser will enact a redirect action through one of the 3xx status codes, the specification doesn't define that a user agent **must** redirect with a 201.  You could try sending a refresh header to see if it forces a redirect to the `Location` header, but I wouldn't count on it.  Why not stick with a 3xx response?

Answer (score 2):

You could send a `Refresh` header.

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with this for the first time, and this is what I have decided to do:

- `GET /user/new` -> `200 Ok` with user registration form.
- `POST /user` -> `201 Created` a new user, respond with the same content as the `GET /user` route.
- `GET /user` -> `200 Ok` with the user profile page for the authenticated user, or, for anonymous visitors, `307 Temporary Redirect` to `/login`, which links to `/user/new`.

**update**

I have found out that this is a bad idea, because if the user refreshes the page that was rendered as a response for `POST /user`, they resend the post data. I will leave the answer here in case anyone else has the same brilliant idea.

Comment: Thank you for leaving that update.  I was thinking along the same lines, and you probably just saved me a bunch of work.