# REST Api - Created resource redirect

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, http-headers, postman

I'm building REST API, and when resource is created normally I return HTTP 201 Created along with Location header to specify where that resource is located. But from some reason http client is not redirecting.

I'm using Postman for this. Does anyone have idea on this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In short, a Location header is not sufficient to trigger a client redirect.  It must be used in conjunction with a 3xx HTTP status code.

References:

1. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location
2. [Redirecting with a 201 created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584728/redirecting-with-a-201-created)

Comment: But It should do that

Comment: According to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), a 201 should not do this.  I would recommend a 303 like in the answer of the question linked in the answer above.

Comment: Its not that 201 is doing this, Location header should force redirec

Comment: Here is HTTP 1.1 Spec about 201 201 Created

The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created. The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for the resource given by a Location header field. The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.

Comment: Correct.  It says a Location header should be included to indicate the location of the new resource.  It does not say that the client should redirect, though.  The 3xx response specs, on the other hand, do have something to say about redirection.  See this explanation of the location header on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things where the expectation does not meet what actually happens, and the first thing people think is "well that doesn't work properly", as has been suggested in other comments.

The Location is just a random header, and clients, such as Postman or curl or anything else need to be instructed to follow them. Most won't do this by default, as that is an unreasonable default.

YouTube for example returns a body for some responses and a Location tag too. One example would be video uploads. They respond to your original meta-data for the video is sent with a POST, and they shove a Location URL which is the endpoint to upload the video too. If clients just randomly redirected to that you'd be having a bad time.

You can use [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) to make a "sequence", which I believe will let you take values from headers to reuse. This is also possible with [Runscope Ghostinspector](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-qN2M3IbKAhVDND4KHa7ICpYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.runscope.com%2Fghostinspector&usg=AFQjCNGJVRcCo4942Ma-q9c-h46cGq0epw&bvm=bv.110151844,d.eWE).